# Why and how should demonic items be blessed before being destroyed?

Tags: catholicism, demons, exorcism, blessings

Just listened to Feb 2nd, 2023 episode of Pint With Aquinas. Fr. Vincent Lampert says that a voodoo doll or similar items should be blessed before being destroyed. Is it possible to bless something evil?  Guessing this is something only a priest should do, but is it only an priest trained in exorcism. And why would something need to be blessed rather than just destroyed.  Should these things be destroyed if it's easier to just throw it away, because it seems like sometimes a proper blessing/destruction would take longer and increase the likelihood of demonic infestation?

Answer (score 2):

**Why and how should demonic items be blessed before being destroyed?**

The Vatican exorcist Fr. Gabriele Amorth in his book ***An Exorcist Tells His Story*** explained that he learned how to do exorcism from Fr.Candido Amantini. One day, after the liberation of a victim of exorcism, Fr. Candido forgot to bless the object by which the Demon possessed the individual. Fr. Amantini desiring to destroy the object by burning it, picked up the object inadvertently, and regretted this action for many years. This hand suffered much pain for several years afterwards.

Thus explains why Catholic exorcists bless items that are somehow attached to the service of Satan. Usually the **sign of the cross** and then sprinkled with **holy water** will suffice.

I know of other priests that have burned demonic objects in an outdoor fire. I remember one priest burning such an item in a [St. John's Eve Bonfire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_John%27s_Eve) (June 23). I will spare the details of how the Demon hated being thrown into a Blessed Bonfire because it could frighten some. Priests will generally accomplish this last action privately and without fanfare.

The Bonfire of St. John the Baptist (June 23) is an historical Catholic custom that goes back many centuries and has a special blessing reserved for the Eve of the Feast of St. John the Baptist ([**Benedictio Rogi *quæ fit a Clero extra ecclesiam in Vigilia S. Joannis Baptistæ***](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf) (Page 318).

I remember St. Mary of Jesus Crucified response to the many insults of Satan, who hoped to break her resolve to be a saint: May God bless you! The Demon left her presence instantly...

The Demon abhors God’s blessings!

> [**What can be done to counteract a curse?**](https://catholicexchange.com/blessing-curse/)
>
> Fr. Fortea advises, “If he is truly under a curse, the only way to remove it is to do just the opposite. That is to say, if a person has invoked a demon to do evil, then one has to invoke God to protect, help and bless him. Good is always stronger than evil.”
>
> Fortea’s advice echoes Christ’s teaching, “But to you who hear I say love your enemies, do good to those who hate you, bless those who curse you, pray for those who maltreat you (Luke 6:27-28).” The Lord has given us the opportunity to bless or curse by the power of our tongue so vigilance is necessary.

It seems blessing breaks a curse that is attached to as one particular object that is employed by Satan to possess individuals! An exorcist can not take the chance the the Demon is somehow still link to a certain item. It must be blessed and then immediately destroyed, usually by fire.